# angular - module federation different versions

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, module, webpack-module-federation

I have quite a big problem with connecting several versions of angular.

shell application uses version 14.0.0, it needs lazyLoad to connect angular version 12, here there is a problem because the application is quite large it has several modules, previously it was downloaded as one large module and it worked, as the shell application was raised to version 14.0.0 the problems started. I tried with angular Elements but routing and default module loading doesn't work.I tried to give `stalone: ​​true` but then the application loads without any error but the whole middle is empty :/, I tried with guides from
angulararchitects.io but unfortunately nothing works :/, Any ideas?

application shell

```
const { shareAll, withModuleFederationPlugin } = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ requiredVersion: '12.0.0 < 15.0.0' }),
  },

});
```

mf who wants to join in shell

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const {dependencies: deps} = require("./package.json");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "rootConfigWeb",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({

        // For remotes (please adjust)
         name: "rootConfigWeb",
         filename: "remoteEntry.js",
         exposes: {
           //rootConfigRoot: './src/bootstrap.ts',
           rootConfigRoot: './/src/app/root-config/root-config.module.ts',
         },

        shared: share({
          '@angular/core': {  requiredVersion: deps['@angular/core'] },
          '@angular/common': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/common'] },
          '@angular/common/http': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/common'] },
          '@angular/router': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/router'] },
          '@angular/forms': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/forms'] },
          '@angular/platform-browser': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/platform-browser'] },
          '@angular/platform-browser/animations': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/platform-browser'] },
          '@angular/animations': { requiredVersion: deps['@angular/animations'] },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```